# What does it mean to unravel a circular linked list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, data-structures, linked-list, frontend

I came across [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v16.12.0/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L741) comment whilst looking through React's hooks implementation. By way of background, internally hooks are stored on each component's fiber object as a linked list and according to this comment, the updates on each hook are stored as a circular linked list the first time around.

> For the first update, the queue is a circular linked list where `queue.last.next = queue.first`. Once the first update commits, and the `baseUpdate` is no longer empty, we can unravel the list.

My computer science knowledge is not very strong and whilst I know a little bit about linked lists, I have never come across the term "unravel". Looking at the implementation, am I correct in thinking it just means turning it back into a regular linked list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full context you're referring to is:

```
// The last update in the entire queue
const last = queue.last;
// The last update that is part of the base state.
const baseUpdate = hook.baseUpdate;
const baseState = hook.baseState;

// Find the first unprocessed update.
let first;
if (baseUpdate !== null) {
  if (last !== null) {
    // For the first update, the queue is a circular linked list where
    // `queue.last.next = queue.first`. Once the first update commits, and
    // the `baseUpdate` is no longer empty, we can unravel the list.
    last.next = null;
  }
  first = baseUpdate.next;
} else {
  first = last !== null ? last.next : null;
}
```

Your thinking is correct; `last.next = null;` does "unravel" the circular linked list by setting the `last.next` reference to `null` which turns it into a linear chain rather than a loop.

As for the terminology, I don't think it's particularly common and see no direct precedents with a bit of web searching, so it's probably something they came up with on the spot to describe what the code does in a casual way.